# Параллельные состояния в QStateMachine

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-faq

В справке Qt довольно подробно расписано использование конечного автомата `QStateMachine` в случае с последовательно меняющимися состояниями. Однако реализация автомата с распараллеливанием не имеет примеров и описывается лишь диаграммой, да парой абзацев текста на английском языке, не сильно вносящих ясности.

Как реализовать параллельные состояния и переходы между ними в `QStateMachine`? Отдельно хотелось бы увидеть организацию переходов посредством использования событий вместо сигналов, поскольку вторые не во всех случаях удобно использовать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Реализация параллельных состояний в Qt State Machine Framework в отличие от последовательных имеет одну существенную особенность. Но для полноты картины начнём именно с последовательных. Создадим машину и пару состояний.

```
QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine();
QState *state1 = new QState(machine);
QState *state2 = new QState(machine);
```

Если для нашей машины предполагается, что она, при наличии определённых условий (скажем, при прохождении двух ранее объявленных состояний), должна завершить свою работу, то удобно добавить в неё состояние завершения работы.

```
QFinalState *final_state = new QFinalState(machine);
```

Использование `QFinalState` удобно тем, что при входе в него контекста выполнения этот тип состояния автоматически отправляет своему родителю сигнал `finished()`. Если родителем является объект `QStateMachine`, то машина будет остановлена, если же это объект `QState`, то уже тот в свою очередь отправит такой же сигнал вверх по цепочке. Эта особенность в полной мере используется и при параллельном подключении состояний, что будет рассмотрено ниже.

К слову сказать, во всех примерах Qt-справки машина имеет неопределённую длительность жизни, тогда как на практике часто встречаются задачи, которые, с одной стороны требуют асинхронного выполнения (например, отправка и обработка сетевых запросов), а с другой - возникают по мере необходимости. Нет никакого интереса содержать в памяти объект машины со всеми состояниями, если, скажем, надо что-то выполнять регулярно, но не постоянно.

Для таких случаев при объявлении машины можно просто подключить соответствующие сигналы и объект машины ликвидирует сам себя и все дочерние объекты, как только завершит работу.

```
connect(machine, &QStateMachine::stopped, machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
connect(machine, &QStateMachine::finished, machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
```

Для переключения состояний обычно используют сигналы от внешних по отношению к машине объектов.

```
state1->addTransition(external_obj1, SIGNAL(customSignal()), state2);
state2->addTransition(external_obj2, SIGNAL(customSignal()), final_state);
```

Однако этот вариант не подходит, если таковых объектов не имеется. В этом случае можно добавить в класс, в котором существует объект машины, собственный произвольный сигнал. Например:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        void customSignal();

    public:
        MyObject(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QObject(parent) {}

    public slots:
        void run();
};

void MyClass::run() {
    QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(this);

    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::stopped
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::finished
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);    

    QState *state1 = new QState(machine);
    connect(state1, &QState::entered, [this]() {
        // Код при входе в первое состояние ...
        emit customSignal();
    });

    QState *state2 = new QState(machine);
    connect(state2, &QState::entered, [this]() {
        // Код при входе во второе состояние ...
        emit customSignal();
    });

    QFinalState *final_state = new QFinalState(machine);
    connect(final_state, &QFinalState::entered, [this]() {
        // Здесь, например, можно уведомить
        // пользователя о завершении работы.
    });

    // Подключаем переходы.
    state1->addTransition(this, SIGNAL(customSignal()), state2);
    state2->addTransition(this, SIGNAL(customSignal()), final_state);

    // Указываем точку входа и активируем машину.
    machine->setInitialState(state1);
    machine->start();
}
```

Однако такой подход приводит к проблемам при необходимости расширения типов реакции машины на каждое из состояний.

Предположим, что теперь требуется учитывать успешно или неуспешно завершились `state1` и `state2`. Конечно, можно добавить ещё несколько сигналов в `MyClass`, но что за "ёрш" в итоге получится, если и количество состояний будет расти? Очевидно, что в данной ситуации требуется знать не только результат выполнения кода при выходе из каждого состояния, но и, собственно, что это было за состояние из списка имеющихся. Помочь может использование событий и переходов (`transition`) по событиям.

Для начала класс произвольного события **stateevent.h**:

```
#include <QtCore/QEvent>

class QState;

class StateEvent : public QEvent {
    public:
        enum Result {
            RESULT_NULL,
            RESULT_SUCCEED,
            RESULT_FAILED
        };

        static const QEvent::Type &_event_type;

        StateEvent(QState *state, Result result);

        QState *state() const {return _state;}

        StateEvent::Result result() const {return _result;}

    private:
        QState *_state;
        Result _result;
};
```

... и **stateevent.cpp**:

```
#include "stateevent.h"

const QEvent::Type &StateEvent::_event_type
    = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::registerEventType());

StateEvent::StateEvent(QState *state, Result result)
    : QEvent(_event_type), _state(state), _result(result) {}
```

А теперь и класс перехода:

```
#include <QtCore/QAbstractTransition>

#include "stateevent.h"

class StateTransition : public QAbstractTransition {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        StateTransition(QState *source_state = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QAbstractTransition(source_state)
            , _result(StateEvent::RESULT_NULL) {}

        StateEvent::Result eventResult() const {return _result;}
        void setEventResult(StateEvent::Result result) {_result = result;}

    protected:
        virtual bool eventTest(QEvent *event) {
            if(event->type() == StateEvent::_event_type) {
                StateEvent *state_event = static_cast<StateEvent*>(event);
                return (state_event->state() == sourceState()
                    && state_event->result() == _result);
            }

            return false;
        }

        virtual void onTransition(QEvent *event) {Q_UNUSED(event);}

    private:
        StateEvent::Result _result;
};
```

Метод `eventTest(QEvent*)` проверяет, соответствует ли объект состояния (`QState`) и результат выполнения (`StateEvent::Result`) объекту перехода (`StateTransition`). Если истина, то машина переключится в новое состояние, которое назначено при выполнении перечисленных условий.

Теперь код активации машины меняется на следующий (произвольные сигналы нам больше не нужны):

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyObject(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
            : QObject(parent) {}

    public slots:
        void run();
};

void MyClass::run() {
    QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(this);

    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::stopped
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::finished
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);    

    QState *state1 = new QState(machine);
    connect(state1, &QState::entered, [this,state1]() {
        // Код при входе в первое состояние ...
        bool result = ... ;

        if(result == true) {
            state1->machine()
                ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state1
                    , StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED));
        } else {
            state1->machine()
                ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state1
                    , StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED));
        }
    });

    QState *state2 = new QState(machine);
    connect(state2, &QState::entered, [this,state2]() {
        // Код при входе во второе состояние ...
        bool result = ... ;

        if(result == true) {
            state2->machine()
                ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state2
                    , StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED));
        } else {
            state2->machine()
                ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state2
                    , StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED));
        }
    });

    QFinalState *final_state = new QFinalState(machine);
    connect(final_state, &QFinalState::entered, [this]() {
        // Здесь, например, можно уведомить
        // пользователя о завершении работы.
    });

    // Подключаем переходы.
    {
        StateTransition *success_transition = new StateTransition();
        success_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED);
        success_transition->setTargetState(state2);

        StateTransition *fail_transition = new StateTransition();
        fail_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED);
        fail_transition->setTargetState(final_state);

        state1->addTransition(success_transition);
        state1->addTransition(fail_transition);
    }

    {
        StateTransition *success_transition = new StateTransition();
        success_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED);
        success_transition->setTargetState(final_state);

        StateTransition *fail_transition = new StateTransition();
        fail_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED);
        fail_transition->setTargetState(final_state);

        state2->addTransition(success_transition);
        state2->addTransition(fail_transition);
    }

    // Указываем точку входа и активируем машину.
    machine->setInitialState(state1);
    machine->start();
}
```

С помощью продемонстрированного механизма можно свободно "плодить" различные типы результата работы для состояний, что в свою очередь позволит конечному автомату переключать эти самые состояния в той последовательности и по тем правилам, что заранее были для него определены.

При отправке события о завершении работы каждого из состояний, например:

```
state1->machine()
    ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state1
        , StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED));
```

... в `StateEvent` вносится и сохраняется указатель на объект состояния, из которого должен быть осуществлён переход. При этом метод `QStateMachine::postEvent(QEvent*)` отправит вновь созданное событие всем объектам перехода, которые были зарегистрированы на этапе создания конечного автомата, а те уже проверят самостоятельно, соответствует ли кому-нибудь из них это событие.

При последовательном подключении состояний сохранять объект состояния (`QState`), из которого должен быть осуществлён переход, необязательно, поскольку в этом режиме работы в конечном автомате (`QStateMachine`) текущим может быть только одно состояние. Достаточно отправлять лишь сведения о результате выполнения. Но всё меняется, если состояния подключаются параллельно: одно событие переключит сразу нескольких, что во многих случаях приведёт к непредсказуемому результату. Сохранение же указателя на источник перехода позволит избежать обозначенной проблемы.

Осталось поменять код из примера выше для параллельного подключения состояний.

```
void MyClass::run() {
    QStateMachine *machine = new QStateMachine(QState::ParallelStates, this);

    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::stopped
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);
    connect(machine, &QStateMachine::finished
        , machine, &QStateMachine::deleteLater);    

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        QState *parent_state = new QState(machine);

        QState *state = new QState(parent_state);
        connect(state, &QState::entered, [this,state]() {
            // Код при входе в **i-ое** состояние ...
            bool result = ... ;

            if(result == true) {
                state->machine()
                    ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state
                        , StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED));
            } else {
                state->machine()
                    ->postEvent(new StateEvent(state
                        , StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED));
            }
        });

        QFinalState *final_state = new QFinalState(parent_state);

        StateTransition *success_transition = new StateTransition();
        success_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_SUCCEED);
        success_transition->setTargetState(final_state);

        StateTransition *fail_transition = new StateTransition();
        fail_transition->setEventResult(StateEvent::RESULT_FAILED);
        fail_transition->setTargetState(final_state);

        state->addTransition(success_transition);
        state->addTransition(fail_transition);
    }

    // Активируем машину (указывать точку входа нужды нет).
    machine->start();
}
```

Поскольку `QStateMachine` является наследником `QState` мы имеем возможность объявить посредством установки флага `QState::ParallelStates`, что дочерние состояния машины должны быть подключены в параллельном режиме. Это указание действует только на тех из них, для которых объект конечного автомата является непосредственным родителем.

Таким образом в теле цикла в параллельный режим войдут только копии `parent_state`, тогда как уже их дочерние состояния останутся по умолчанию - подключенными последовательно.

Разумеется, что именно такое построение как в примере вовсе необязательно и объекты `QState` (в т.ч. `QStateMachine`) можно компоновать с любым количеством иерархических уровней, однако последний, самый низкий уровень должен быть представлен в виде последовательного подключения как минимум одного `QState` и `QFinalState`, поскольку только тогда "наверх" по иерархии будет отправлен сигнал о завершении работы.

Да, можно обойтись даже и одним `QFinalState`, но тогда необходимо иметь в виду, что сигнал `finished()` будет отправлен прежде, чем будет выполнен вход в состояние `QFinalState`, а значит код, ассоциированный с ним, будет также выполнен позднее. Для многих задач это бывает неприемлемо.

Каждый из `parent_state` в примере будет выполняться параллельно по отношению к другому, и может закончить свою работу раньше, либо позднее других. Однако при этом `QStateMachine` не остановится, несмотря на то, что от одного из выполнившихся `parent_state` к нему придёт сигнал `finished()`. Лишь только тогда, когда все `parent_state` завершат свою работу, только тогда конечный автомат завершит и свою, отправив `finished()`, но уже от себя.

`QStateMachine` чрезвычайно мощный и гибкий инструмент, и совершенно напрасно многие считают его избыточным, либо подходящим лишь для подключения анимации. Этот фреймворк содержится в модуле `QtCore` и может быть весьма полезен для реализации практически любых задач, требующих, прежде всего, асинхронного выполнения.